# Automatically logging in website using VB script

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, vbscript, automation

I am trying to automate login process for a website. I used below code

```
Dim objIE
Dim htmld
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Visible = False
objIE.Navigate "website.com"  //website.com is example not the original
While objIE.Busy
WScript.Sleep 400
Wend
WScript.Sleep 500
objIE.Document.getElementById("login_id").value = "ss"
```

the html code for the textbox login_id is

```
<TABLE id=logintable cellSpacing=0><TBODY>
<TR>
<TD><IMG src="/nfusion/default/en_US/images/sign_in_flag.gif"></TD>
<TD class=tdlabel>User ID:</TD>
<TD><INPUT id=login_id class=txt name=login_id></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD></TD>
```

I am getting error of the interface is unknown. I have changed the security and login_id does not have tag so i was  not able to use getElementByTag.

Comment: Why VBScript? Why not JavaScript?

Comment: coz i am using VBS for related function. Why down votes ?

Comment: What is the host you are running? VBA or WSH VBS? Remove extraneous tag. What security did you change and how? What do you mean saying `getElementByTag`? There is no such method.

Comment: @user3201928 Okay, not sure about the downvotes...

Comment: @user3201928 I voted you up, this is a great question, and the answer I provided below I use everyday to do exactly what you have asked. It saves me a lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a vbscript to do just what you asked, and I use it all the time. It opens up one tab in IE, and logs in, then it opens two more tabs to different pages in our application.

```
On Error Resume Next

ECRecord = "http://vm195/views/welcome.action"
ECJobs = "http://vm195/views/job/jobList.action?query.MaxResults=500&allStates=false%2F&query.ActiveState=true&query.ActiveState=false%2F&query.PendingState=true&query.PendingState=false%2F&query.CompletedState=false%2F&query.FailedState=true&query.FailedState=false%2F&query.CancelledState=true&query.CancelledState=false%2F&query.HoldState=true&query.HoldState=false%2F&query.jobTypes=-1&allFreqs=true&allFreqs=false%2F&query.DailyFrequency=true&query.DailyFrequency=false%2F&query.IntervalFrequency=true&query.IntervalFrequency=false%2F&query.SetDateFrequency=true&query.SetDateFrequency=false%2F&query.SingleFrequency=true&query.SingleFrequency=false%2F&query.patientId=&query.accessionNumber=&query.studyPk=&query.dateRange=-3&query.beginDate=&query.endDate=&Submit=Search&refreshRate=120"
ECConfig = "http://vm195/views/org/organizationTree.action"

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible = True
'open a new window
oIE.Navigate2 ECRecord

Do While (oIE.Busy)
   WScript.Sleep 10
 Loop                    


 Set Helem = oIE.document.getElementByID("username")
 Helem.Value = "tsu500" ' change this to yours
 Set Helem = oIE.document.getElementByID("password")
 Helem.Value = "production" ' change this to yours

 oIE.Document.getElementsByName("submit_button").Item(0).Click

 'Set Helem = oIE.document.Forms(1)
 'Helem.Submit


WScript.Sleep 500


Do While (oIE.Busy)
   WScript.Sleep 10
 Loop  


'open url In new tab
oIE.Navigate2 ECJobs, 2048
WScript.Sleep 100
oIE.Navigate2 ECConfig, 2048

Set oIE = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these additional checks:

```
Dim IE
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = False
    .Navigate "website.com" ' website.com is example not the original
    Do While .Busy Or Not .readyState = 4: WScript.Sleep 100: Loop
    Do Until .document.readyState = "complete": WScript.Sleep 100: Loop
    Do While TypeName(.document.getElementById("login_id")) = "Null": WScript.Sleep 100: Loop
    .document.getElementById("login_id").Value = "ss"
End With
```

Comment: Object doesn't support this property or method error