# VB Script to login in website and navigate to other page and press a button

Tags: vbscript

I am not a VB developer but I have a requirement to write a VB script to login in a website , navigate to another page and click and button there

I checked codes on internet and found this VBA code

http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2011/03/08/get-data-from-website-that-requires-a-login/#comment-997146

I also referred other link like

[VBScript to Launch a website login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221907/vbscript-to-launch-a-website-login)

but i am getting error and i need the code to navigate to another page and click on a button.

If anyone can suggest me some code which can do the same in VB script, that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer I posted for logging in to a website using VBScript.

[Automatically logging in website using VB script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33958079/automatically-logging-in-website-using-vb-script/34076538#34076538)